# VB.NET Tabs duplicados con variables en común

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un Form1 que cuando añado Tabs "pestañas", se duplica la Tab1 en la nueva pestaña haciendo addtab y inherits.

El problema es que tengo 2 variables que si se actualiza alguna de ellas en un Tab, la actualización se debe replicar en todos los Tabs. Y no sé como hacerlo.

Por si alguien no sabe de qué hablo, pongo un ejemplo:

Tengo un Form1 con un botón de añadir. 
Al pulsar el botón de añadir, se creará una nueva página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al añadirse el Tab2, se hará un Inherits del Tab1 para heredar sus características. Por ejemplo el fondo blanco.

En este caso, al tener 2 Tabs duplicados, necesito que estos tabs puedan leer continuamente un valor, por ejemplo una variable. Si uno de ellos se actualiza, se actualizará el cambio también en los otros Tabs, independientemente del numero de Tabs que existan.

Quizás moviendo esas variables a una clase aparte?

Alguna idea mejor? Porqué con una variable igual da el pego pero con un control por ejemplo un timer, ahí ya no sé...

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: supongo que es winforms no? aclaralo por favor. y si las pestañas son el mismo form, no entiendo porque necesitas varias. Podrias mostrar el diseño de tu form y tu clase?

Comment: Si es VB.NET, la clase TabPage se encuentra en el ensamblado System.Windows.Forms, por lo que no hay otra opción.

Necesito varias pestañas porqué el programa está hecho así por muchos motivos, para explicar porqué está hecho así os tengo que explicar otro programa entero, ya que esto es un bot que trabaja sobre otro proceso. Intento mantener el post breve y directo para algo relativamente sencillo...

Comment: El post debe ser completo y permitir reproducir el problema. Asi como esta no se entiende cual ea el problema. Mira [ask] y tambien [mcve]